# ODE second order and Bessel function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

I have a function $xy''-y'+y=0$ 
that I'm trying to solve. I thought of solving it like this
$
y''-y'/x+y/x=0
$
this you can write as $(y'/x)'+y=0 $ and then you can find the solution as a Bessel function.
I got 
$y(x)=c_1x^1J_a(ax^b)+c_2x^1Y_a(ax^b)$ $a=2/3$  and $ b=3/2$

did I get it right?

Thanks
Nachum

Comment: You may have a mistake somewhere. What I found is $y(x)=c_1 x J_2\left(2 \sqrt{x}\right)+ c_2 x Y_2\left(2 \sqrt{x}\right)$

Comment: o.k thanks I see it I did c-a=-1 but a=-1 so it is realy c-(-1)=-1 so c is 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the answer for example in http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0206.pdf.